# Retrieving/adding data from/to a stored procedure

Tags: sql, vb.net, html, data-binding

Alright so I have this webpage that I have to create and it has 3 pages and a master page. Now basically all of it is working, except the fact that I can't seem to get data coming into the webpage when requested via a retrieve button, nor will it update or add data to the SQL table. Now in my queries page when I put `Select * From Customer` it brings back the data in the table so that part works. From what I have to work with in the pdf's provided, they want me to use

```
TextBox1.Text = table.Rows(0).Field<string>("TextBox1")  
TextBox1.DataBind()
```

To retrieve the data from the sql, now it comes up with an error saying `Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Field' accepts this number of arguments`.

So here is my Customer page

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.DataRowCollection

Public Class Customer
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbConnection1").ConnectionString)
Shadows adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()
// Tells me to use Shadows because variable adapter conflicts with property 'adapter'
Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable()
Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()

Protected Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Try
        conn = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbConnection1").ConnectionString)
        Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
        command.Connection = conn
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Acme_Customer VALUES(" & txtCustID.Text & ",'" & txtFirstname.Text & "',  '" & txtSurname.Text & "', " & txtGender.Text & ",  " + txtAge.Text & ", " & txtAddress1.Text & ", " & txtAddress2.Text & ", " & txtCity.Text & ", " + txtPhone.Text & ", " + txtMobile.Text & ", " & txtEmail.Text & ")"
        command.Connection.Open()
        adapter.InsertCommand = command
        adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        command.Connection.Close()
        Clear()
        lblMessage.Text = "You have been successfully added into our records"
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblMessage.Text = "Something has gone wrong with adding you to our records, please double check everything as we want you to become a member."
    End Try
End Sub


 Protected Sub btnRetrieve_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRetrieve.Click

    Try
        command.Connection = conn
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        command.CommandText = "GetCustomer"
        command.Connection.Open()
        Dim param As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter()
        param.ParameterName = "@ID"
        param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        param.Value = txtCustID.Text
        command.Parameters.Add(param)

        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        adapter.Fill(table)

    txtFirstname.Text = table.Rows(0).Field<string>("Firstname")
        txtFirstname.DataBind()
    txtSurname.Text = table.Rows(0).Field<string>("Surname")
        txtSurname.DataBind()
    txtGender.Text = table.Rows(0).Field<String>("Gender")
        txtGender.DataBind()
    txtAge.Text = table.Rows(0).Field<Integer>("Age")
        txtAge.DataBind()
    txtAddress1.Text = table.Rows(0).Field<String>("Address1")
        txtAddress1.DataBind()
    txtAddress2.Text = table.Rows(0).Field<String>("Address2")
        txtAddress2.DataBind()
    txtCity.Text = table.Rows(0).Field<String>("City")
        txtCity.DataBind()
    txtPhone.Text = table.Rows(0).Field<Integer>("Phone Number")
        txtPhone.DataBind()
    txtMobile.Text = table.Rows(0).Field<Integer>("Mobile Number")
        txtMobile.DataBind()
    txtEmail.Text = table.Rows(0).Field<String>("Email")
        txtEmail.DataBind()
   Catch ex As Exception
        lblMessage.Text = "The ID you have entered doesn't exist."
    End Try

End Sub
```

So I'm just wondering what I've written wrong or if I should be using other code instead of what I have here, I know I should be using C# but I just got the hang of vb so, hopefully I can just start using C# after this project.

Comment: Ahh! a good opportunity of SQL Injection there in `btnAdd_Click`

Comment: "I know I should be using C#" - why? There's no 'should' involved. If you want to use C#, go ahead and learn it now. There's no point in learning VB if you want to use C#. Conversely VB is perfectly OK too.  They are just two dialects of the same language. In fact the code you've shown us above would be almost identical in C# anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Sub btnRetrieve_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRetrieve.Click
Try
    command.Connection = conn
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    command.CommandText = "GetCustomer"
    command.Connection.Open()
    Dim param As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter()
    param.ParameterName = "@ID"
    param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int
    param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    param.Value = txtCustID.Text
    command.Parameters.Add(param)

    adapter.SelectCommand = command
    adapter.Fill(table)
    dim objDV as dataview = table.defaultview

txtFirstname.Text = objDV(0)("Firstname").tostring
txtSurname.Text = objDV(0)("Surname").tostring
' Fill all other text boxes following above lines

   Catch ex As Exception
        lblMessage.Text = "The ID you have entered doesn't exist."
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Tried that out and I was getting exception for trying to convert the parameter from a string to an int. At the 'adapter.Fill(table) is where it was crashing down. Not quite sure if it's meant to be involved since you have Dataview in there, but I can't think of what to change that to.